# How to add required filed once information has been entered for any field in the row, all fields in that row should be required too

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have module where I need to put attribute of required field on all inputs and selects on specific index. So now when the users or user trying to **select or input a data on the specific table row** the system will **add automatically a attribute of required**.

**The library that I used is React JS**

**Goal** : Once the handler determine that there is changes on the row 1 it will add required attribute only on the specific table row where the user input the data, not on all table rows.

```js
handleInputChange = (e, index) => {
  
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Add New Employee</h1>
<table classname="employee">
  <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Gender</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="First Name"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="Last Name"/></td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select Gender</option>
        <option value="Male">Male</option>
        <option value="Female">Female</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="First Name"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="Last Name"/></td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select Gender</option>
        <option value="Male">Male</option>
        <option value="Female">Female</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear to me, but these days having only 2 options for gender is quite limited. For a future-proof app, you might want to add gender options like: self-described, prefer not to tell, other. Also, consider an iterator, instead of copy-paste identical code block twice, or perhaps even more

Comment: @Roland hi roland, all inputs selects are shown in the description is just example, I can't show the data because very sensitive. and sorry for that.

Comment: I guess this is the right specific question for that.  I have a task where once information has been entered for any field in the row, all fields in that row should be required too.

Comment: Why do you use React JS ?

Comment: @Dilshan because that is our requirements.

Comment: You mentioned that "The library that I used is React JS" but I don't see a place where you use React js ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a `key` index on each row of inputs, and `onchange` events on the inputs. The onchange handler could add an asterisk on all empty inputs on the specific row, or color those with a red background. With react, using an iterator forces you to put in a key index. E.g:

```
{this.state.rows.map((row, iRow) =>
    <tr key={iRow}>
        <td>{row.RowNr}</td>
        <td>{row.Crate}</td>
    </tr>
)}
```

This just shows how to iterate, but you want inputs where I have just values and you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply need to add the `required` property to all of those inputs, and you would like to do so using JS rather than in the HTML for whatever reason, a simple `.forEach()` loop should do the trick:

```js
employeeTableFields.forEach(field => field.required = true);
```

Here is a full live example of this applied to your original source code:

```js
const employeeTable = document.querySelector('table[classname="employee"]');
const employeeTableFields = Array.from(employeeTable.querySelectorAll('input, select, textarea'));

employeeTableFields.forEach(field => field.required = true);

handleInputChange = (e, index) => {
  
};
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<h1>Add New Employee</h1>
<table classname="employee">
  <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Gender</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="First Name"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="Last Name"/></td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select Gender</option>
        <option value="Male">Male</option>
        <option value="Female">Female</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="First Name"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="Last Name"/></td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select Gender</option>
        <option value="Male">Male</option>
        <option value="Female">Female</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: this is correct btw, but I want to required all fields on the specific index where the user input the information.

Comment: @DevGe so if I'm understanding correctly, you only want to mark the field as required if a user populates it? Should we also un-require it if a user empties a field?

Comment: to be exact what i mean. adding a attribute required should be once information has been entered for any field in the row, all fields in that row should be required too.